# Destructuring a JavaScript Array by a Variable Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

To my understanding, JavaScript arrays can be destructured according to a specific index by doing the following.

```
const { 3: selectedByIndex } = arr;
```

This would assign the value of the element at index 3 to the variable `selectedByIndex`.

Is there a way to pass in a variable index value to destructure the array? The below does not work, it seems to instead look for the `index` property on `arr`.

```
const index = 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const { index: selectedByIndex } = arr;
```

Comment: Is `const selectedByIndex = arr[index];` too "old skool" for kids these days? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can by setting `index` inside the square brackets.

```js
const index = 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const { [index]: selectedByIndex } = arr;

console.log(selectedByIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

While this works

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const index = 2;

const [,,v1] = a;
// v1 = 3
const { [index]: v2 } = a;
// v2 = 3
```

The second solution (`v2`) is a bad design practice, because an array is not an object, but you are accessing it as one.

A better solution would be either

```
const v3 = a[index]; 
const v4 = a?.[index];
```

In other words, destructuring is when you know the format of the data structure. If not, JavaScript arrays don't care if you try to get an out-of-bound value, unless the value is not an array, in which case you need optional chaining (e.g. `v4`).

---

#### Edit 2022

To clarify what I meant by the second solution being a "bad design practice", consider [this benchmark](https://jsbench.me/yxl8m98kkq/1):

```
// tested on                      Chrome 105       Firefox 105
let value = list[index];       // fastest, base    fastest, base
let value = list?.[index];     // 2.52% slower     3.74% slower
let { [index]: value } = list; // 47.72% slower    30.76% slower
```

It's not because a feature exist, and it works, that 1) it's efficient or 2) it's a good design choice. After all, I can certainly hit a nail with a pipe wrench, but there are better tools for the job.

---

#### Edit 2024

When the previous edit was added, [Array.at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) was still not generally adopted, however now it is.

```
const v5 = a.at(index);
```

This is the preferred way because it is a disambiguation from accessing object properties.

For example:

```
const i = 1;
const p = 'find';

// old
const v6 = a[i];  // 2
const v7 = a[p];  // 'find() [native code]' (same as a.find)

// new
const v8 = a.at(i);  // 2
const v9 = a.at(p);  // 1 (same as a.at(0)
```

The new API protects from returning unwanted values by accessing undesired properties.

**Bonus:** `a.at(-2)` is the same as `a[a.length - 2]`

Comment: `"The second solution (v2) is a bad design practice, because an array is not an object..."`.
I don't think that is a bad practice. `Arrays` in JavaScript are `Objects` like almost everything in JavaScript.

Comment: @Xion14 please, read my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you pass a variable key when creating an object -- put it in `[]`.

```js
const index = 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const { [index]: selectedByIndex } = arr;
console.log(selectedByIndex);
```

But unless this is just a part of a more complex destructuring pattern, `arr[index]` is obviously simpler.